# How can I use nginx for load balancer -simple node.js with docker compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, devops

I am googling and trying to use nginx for simple node.js application with docker compose. But when I look at localhost:8081 My request returned me as 502 bad gate way. How can I handle this error?

My file structure below:

[image]

Load-Balancer:

DockerFile:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine 
LABEL xxx yyyyyy
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 8081
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf:

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

upstream localhost {
server backend1:3001;
server backend2:3001;
server backend3:3001;
}

server {
listen 8081;
server_name localhost;

location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
}
 }
 }
```

docker-compose.yml

```py
version: '3.2'
services:
  backend1:
      build: ./backend
      tty: true
      volumes:
        - './backend'

  backend2:
      build: ./backend
      tty: true
      volumes:
        - './backend'

  backend3:
      build: ./backend
      tty: true
      volumes:
        - './backend'

  loadbalancer:
      build: ./load-balancer
      tty: true
      links:
          - backend1
          - backend2
          - backend3
      ports:
          - '8081:8081'

volumes:
  backend:
```

**My repository: https://github.com/yusufkaratoprak/nginx_docker_loadbalancer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command set for the `backend` container images to run.

The official nodejs  images run `node` by default, which will start the cli when a `tty` exists. I assuming the tty was enabled in the compose definition to keep the containers from crashing.

A simple `Dockerfile` for an app would look like:

```
FROM node:boron
WORKDIR /app
COPY src/. /app/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "node", "/app/index.js" ]
```

A `tty` shouldn't be needed for most daemons, remove the `tty` settings from the `docker-compose.yml`. The `links` are also redundant in version 2+ compose files.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  backend1:
      build: ./backend
      volumes:
        - './backend'

  backend2:
      build: ./backend
      volumes:
        - './backend'

  backend3:
      build: ./backend
      volumes:
        - './backend'

  loadbalancer:
      build: ./load-balancer
      ports:
          - '8081:8081'

volumes:
  backend:
```